# Mysqli só executa se tiver um submit?

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, tenho um código, explicado a baixo, onde eu quero disponibilizar os arquivos que os usuários fizeram upload para download, para isso fiz um código php, porém a query só é executada se eu fizer o upload de um arquivo, mas eu queria que executasse ao carregar a página, alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer a query ser executado ao iniciar a página ou se tem algo errado com meu código? Desde já agradeço!

Primeiro eu fiz a conexão com o banco de dados, como mostrado a baixo:

```
<?php

class db {
//host
private $host = 'localhost';

//usuario
private $usuario = 'iddsafdsfr';

//senha
private $senha = 'fasdfasd';

//banco de dados
private $database = 'fasdfasdg';

public function conecta_mysql(){

    //criar a conexão
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->database);

    //ajustar a charser de cominicação entre a aplicação e o bd
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    //verificar se houve erro de conexão
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Erro ao tentar se conectar com o banco de dados'.mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $con;
}
}
?>
```

Com a conexão com o banco de dados feita, eu criei a tabela diretamente no phpmyadmin e fiz a parte de formulário, onde o usuário iria inserir os arquivos, como segue no código abaixo:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <center><h1>Plano de aula 1</h1><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
      <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="enviar arquivo" name="enviar">
    </form></center>
  </div>
  </div>
<center><p class="text-success" style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 100px;">
  <?php
  session_start();
  require_once('conecta.php');
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $arq = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    $dataup = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo $dataup;

    $arq = str_replace(" ", "_", $arq);
    $arq = str_replace("ç", "c", $arq);

    if (file_exists("uploads/".$arq)) {
      $a = 1;

      while (file_exists("uploads/[".$a."]".$arq)) {
        $a++;
      }

      $arq = "[".$a."]".$arq;
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$arq)) {
      $objDb = new db();
      $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
      $sql = "insert into arquivos (email_vol, nomearq) values ('".  $email."', '".$arq."')";
      if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo 'Plano de aula 1 enviado com sucesso!';
      } else {
        echo (mysqli_error($link));
        echo 'Erro ao enviar o plano de aula!';
      }

    } else {
      echo "Nenhum arquivo selecionado!";
    }

  } else{

  }
  ?>
</p></center>
```

E por último fiz a parte onde era pra mostrar todos os arquivos que foram feito uploads de acordo com o email e disponibilizar para download. Porém como eu disse antes, a query `$consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");` só é executada se um novo upload for feito, porém eu gostaria que fosse executada ao carregar a página, para que assim o usuário veja quais arquivos ele já fez upload.

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $email = $_SESSION['email'];
      echo $email;
      require_once('conecta.php');
      $pasta = "uploads/";
      $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
      var_dump($consulta);
      while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        echo "<a href=\"" . $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"] . "\">" . $resultado["nomearq"] . "</a><br />";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Arthur com isto só de código não dá pra saber como funciona bem, tente dar uma lida nisto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers e edite a pergunta - fico agradecido.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tentei fazer o melhor pra deixar a pergunta mais completa.

Comment: não entendi muito bem o código... mas tenta criar uma função que executa a query do mysqli, ai coloca pra executar a função no inicio da página, e outra vez quando o input receber o submit

Comment: A função session_start() deve aparecer antes de qualquer tag <html>:

Comment: Para iniciarmos uma session, usamos a função session_start(). 
Para um bom funcionamento, ela não pode estar depois de nenhum OUTPUT de dados (echo, print, códigos HTML, etc.). É recomendável que esteja na primeira linha do código.

Comment: @ArthurOliveira está ultima parte que exibirá os dados esta na mesma página do formulário ou está em outro arquivo?

Comment: @WMomesso está na mesma página do formulário, será que é isso?